# Where is the origin coding of sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits function in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, softmax, cross-entropy

I want to know what the tensorflow function [sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py#L424) mathematically is exactly  doing. But I can't find the origin of the coding. 
Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

[sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/nn/classification#sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits) is equivalent to a numerically stable version of the following:

`-1. * tf.gather(tf.log(tf.nn.softmax(logits)), target)`

or, in more "readable" numpy-code:

`-1. * np.log(softmax(logits))[target]`

where `softmax(x) = np.exp(x)/np.sum(np.exp(x))`.

That is, it computes the softmax of the provided logits, takes the log thereof to retrieve the log-probabilities, and slices the log-probabilities to retrieve the log-probability of the target.

However, it does so in a numerically stable way (a couple of things can go wrong here) by adding small values to some of the operations. This means that computing the above - verbose - version will only approximately result in the same values as `nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` (running some tests showed that the difference is consistently smaller than 2e-6).

Answer (score 0):

The most important part of the implementation is [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/sparse_xent_op.h) starting at line 132.

This functor is called by the [kernel implementation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/sparse_xent_op.cc).

It uses a not-very-well-documented feature of Eigen called generators that allow writing fairly flexible code and have it compile both for CPU and by nvcc for GPU.

Answer (score -1):

In the head version (as of today), you can find the function in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py line #424.

The comment says:

> Measures the probability error in discrete classification tasks in
>   which the   classes are mutually exclusive (each entry is in exactly
>   one class).  For   example, each CIFAR-10 image is labeled with one
>   and only one label: an image   can be a dog or a truck, but not both.