# Not getting same ans as sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to make sure I understand how my cost function is working as my model doesn't seem to be great so I've taken the cost from one mini-batch and tried to manually calculate it to see if I get the same cost. The cost given by Tensorflow is 0.48568. But in my manual attempt below I am getting 0.2109.

As a side note I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37775596/where-is-the-origin-coding-of-sparse-softmax-cross-entropy-with-logits-function) to help me figure out the manual calcs.

[image: Manual Calcs]

Comment: By the way, you don't need to use softmax when doing binary classification. You can just use a logistic loss.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out! I was using log to the base 10 in my calcs (Excel default). When infact it needs to be log to the base e (ln function).